# My app (includes opencv dependencies) runs only on emulator but not on real device

Tags: android-studio, opencv, face-recognition

I'm trying face-recognition with android studio using opencv, for which I have just began loading opencv libraries and dependencies. It works fine on emulator, but the OpenCVLoader.initDebug() returns false when the app runs on real device.

This is my MainActivity.

```
package com.example.opencvtest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    static{
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.i(TAG,"OpenCV Loaded Successfully");
        }
        else{
            Log.i(TAG,"Could not load openCV");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the logs?

Comment: Logs show "Could not load opencv" when connected to device via USB and shows "OpenCV loaded sucessfully" when app runs on emulator.

Comment: OpenCV usually prints something to the logs on init. Do you have any filters on your Logcat putput?